# Google Sheets query I can't select column "BY"

Tags: google-sheets

This works:
`=query(costMarkupLookup!A:CQ, "Select G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,BL,BM,BZ,CA where BM is not null AND BZ > BM ",1)`

If I add col BY in the Select, it doesn't work because it seems to be interpreting column BY as the *keyword* "BY":

`=query(costMarkupLookup!A:CQ, "Select G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,BL,BM,BY,BZ,CA where BM is not null AND BZ > BM ",1)`

I get this error message when I try to include column BY:
*Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " "by" "BY "" at line 1, column 40.*

No doubt this is a bug, but is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use back quote around those columns like-

```
=query(costMarkupLookup!A:CQ, "Select G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,BL,BM,`BY`,BZ,CA where BM is not null AND BZ > BM ",1)
```

Again use back quote, not single quote.

Comment: See this post from [google support](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/2214640/how-to-get-column-which-header-is-by-in-query-function?hl=en).

Answer (score 1):

or wrap your range into `{}` and use Col references

```
=QUERY({costMarkupLookup!A:CQ}, "Select Col7,Col8,.....
```